# Android Gallery children onClickListener

Tags: android, gallery, onclicklistener, baseadapter

I have a Gallery with implemented BaseAdapter. Each view of Gallery contains LinearLayout with many TextVIew. Because I want different onClickListeners for each TextView (loads different web pages) I put onClickListeners  in getView in the adapters. This action (set listeners in getView in the adapter) freeze the Gallery and it's not possible to be scrollable. On the other hand outside of Adapter I can put only listener for the whole Gallery but not specially for each child of each element of the gallery. My question is how I can put  onClickListener in BaseAdapter attached to Gallery for children for each element in Gallery without removing sliding functionality of Gallery.I tried to play with touchevent but doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: it should work like that. What exactly is happening, when you do it? Log and code would be helpful, to help you...

Answer (score 0):

Inside OnItemClickListener,you have to take the id for all child views and check the views over the parent views.while surely you can get the touch for every specific child views,if child view equals to the parent child view.